# WebRTC: how to get the webcam data as a stream of data?

Tags: javascript, webcam, webrtc

I have a simple webpage where you can stream your webcam. I would like to take this stream and send it somewhere, but apparently I can't really access the stream itself. I have this code to run the stream:

```
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({video: true}, gotStream, noStream);
```

And in gotStream, I tried many things to "redirect" this stream somewhere else, for example:

```
function gotStream(stream) {   
    stream_handler(stream)
    //other stuff to show webcam output on the webpage
}
```

or

```
function gotStream(stream) {   
    stream.videoTracks.onaddtrack = function(track){
        console.log("in onaddtrack");
        stream_handler(track);
    }
    //other stuff to show webcam output on the webpage
}
```

But apparently the `gotStream` function gets called only once at the beginning, when the user grants permissions to the webcam to stream. Moreover the `stream` variable is not the stream itself but an object with some properties inside. How am I supposed to access the stream itself and redirect it wherever I want?

EDIT: You may be familiar with webglmeeting, a sort of face2face conversation apparently developed on top of WebRTC. I think that script is sending somehow the stream of data from one point to the other. I would like to achieve the same by understanding how to get the stream of data in the first place.

RE-EDIT: I don't want a conversion to image and sending the latter, I would like to work with the stream of data itself.

Comment: Hi Maisiar, I want to do something similar, did you ever figure out a solution to your problem?

Comment: Hello @jpihl, unfortunately not. Whenever I need to do that, I simply take a snapshot of the canvas where the webcam is and send it as a string through the WebRTC datachannel. If you find a nicer solution let me know! :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you mean to steam your camera to somewhere in PNG or JPG so I will use `canvas` like this

**HTML**

```
<video id="live" width="320" height="240" autoplay></video>
<canvas width="320" id="canvas" height="240" style="display:none;"></canvas>
```

**JS ( jQuery )**

```
var video = $("#live").get()[0];
var canvas = $("#canvas");
var ctx = canvas.get()[0].getContext('2d');

navigator.webkitGetUserMedia("video",
        function(stream) {
            video.src = webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
        }
)
     setInterval(
        function () {
            ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 320,240);
                var data = canvas[0].toDataURL("image/jpeg");   
  },1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no. I would like to access the stream of whatever it's using (bytes anyways) to take it and do something like send it through the net. I don't want to use graphic stuff, since I'm not interested in sending imgs over the net, but the buffer itself.

Comment: Ok, so you have to look at this http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't want to use the WebRTC standard to send the stream, I'm trying to work with an alternate way, and to do so I need the byte stream :(.

Answer (score 0):

Since not too long ago there is now [MediaStream Recording API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API).

The usage is something like this:

```js
const mediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true });
const recorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream);
recorder.ondataavailable = (event) => console.log(event.data);
recorder.start();
setInterval(() => recorder.requestData(), 1000);
```