# Flash based video chats have less overhead than WebRTC?

Tags: html, flash, webrtc

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31355533/how-to-live-stream-with-html5-without-flash) and the OP was asking how he could enable his clients to stream their webcam feed to his server and he wanted to try it with WebRTC. One of the replies (by Tsahi Levent-Levi) was that using WebRTC "incurs a high computing cost on the server side." Using Flash would require just as much computing power, wouldn't it?

Comment: I am not sure where the "high" computing cost would come in. The only cost I can think of is the decrypting->copy->encrypting that has to be done for each webrtc rtp packet. However, I am not an expert in Flash so I do not know if the media is actually encrypted or if anything other than a copy and forward needs to be done.